# Allowing only some given instances of a model to be deleted from the admin

Tags: django, admin

in the admin of a model I would like to allow the delete action only for some of the instances (my model has a DateTimeField and I would like to disable the delete action for instances which have this field set to the current month).

Anybody could help?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried the method proposed by Chris in his anser below, but obj is always None:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):

        # obj is always None

        return super(UserProfileAdmin, self).has_delete_permission(request, obj=obj)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     ...
     def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
         if obj is not None and \
            obj.my_date_field.month == datetime.now().month and \
            obj.my_date_field.year == datetime.now().year:

             return False

         return super(MyModelAdmin, self).has_delete_permission(request, obj=obj)
```

**UPDATE**:

It's not "always None", it's set to a specific object when a specific object can be ascertained. In the changelist, and particularly in your scenario when trying to bulk-delete from the changelist, it's set to `None` because no individual object can obviously be determined.

If you need to account for deletion from the changelist, you'll have to create your own delete action and replace the default Django version. Something like:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = ['limited_delete_selected']

    # Need to remove the default delete_selected action
    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if actions.has_key('delete_selected'):
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def limited_delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
        # filter selected items to only those that are actually deletable
        now = datetime.now()
        queryset = queryset.exclude(date_field__month=now.month, date_field__year=now.year)

        # call Django's delete_selected with limited queryset
        from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected
        delete_selected(self, request, queryset)
    limited_delete_selected.short_description = "Delete selected objects or whatever you want it to say"
```

You actually will need both the action and the original `has_delete_permission` since objects can be deleted individually on their change_form view.

Comment: If I select a few instances of my model in the admin and delete them, the obj variable in has_delete_permission is always None. I edited my question.

Comment: It works BUT we loose Confirmation step. Anyone know how to keep it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs around overriding built-in model methods: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods